# Suppose $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation and $A$ the matrix representation of $T$. Prove that if $A$ is nonsingular, then $T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Please check my attempted proof

$Proof$. Suppose $A$ is a nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix. Then $\exists$ an $n \times n$ matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I_{n}$. Since $A$ represents $T$ and $I_{n}$ represents $id_{W}$ (also $id_{V}$), $\exists S: W \to V$ such that $T \circ S = id_{W}$ (also $S \circ T = id_{V}$). Clearly $S = T^{-1}$. $\square$

Comment: You probably want to say that you define $S$ as the linear transformation corresponding to $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right ideas, but I don't think that you have expressed yourself clearly. Here's how I would write the same proof.

> Suppose that the matrix $A$ associated with $T:V \to W$ is non-singular. Then there exists a matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I_n$. Let $S:W \to V$ be the linear map represented by $A^{-1}$. We observe that
> $$
> AA^{-1} = I_n \implies T \circ S = \operatorname{id}_W,\\
> A^{-1}A = I_n \implies S \circ T = \operatorname{id}_V.
> $$
> Thus, $S = T^{-1}$, so $T$ is indeed invertible.